# Selenium Click Link with Bold Text

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get Selenium Webdriver to click a link that has an xpath that changes frequently, so I cannot count on finding it by relative or absolute xpath.  The page source of the element I'm dealing with looks like ...

```
<a href="https://webpage.com"/>
    <img align="left" border="0" src="/img/folder.png"/>
    <strong>Foobar Folder</strong>
</a>
```

And I'm basically trying to click the link to "Foobar Folder" based on the text of the link itself, "Foobar Folder".  Any suggestions how to best accomplish this?  I'm coding it in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code then:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[.='Foobar Folder']")).click();
```

**It will click on the element having exact innerHTML/text as 'Foobar Folder'.**

Comment: Any reason you'd recommend this solution over just using a findElement(by.linkText("Foobar Folder")).click()?

Comment: Even the `linkText()` method will work for your case. The above is just an alternative to that.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah it's nice because the element you're looking for isn't necessarily a link all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
String path = "//a/strong[contains(text(), 'Foobar Folder')]";
webDriver.findElement(By.xpath(path)).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

The xpath below will find the a tag and click on it.

```
webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//strong[.='Foobar Folder']/..")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

The text is inside of an anchor. So the obvious choice should be: `webDriver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Foobar Folder")).click();`.